# Cannot add a role, Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

so i'm coding a discord bot, and there's a command, this command know when the user changes is custom status, and if the special status is "hello" the bot will send a message in a specific channel, and add a role to the user. But the code gives my an error

Here's the code :

```
bot.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    console.log(newMember.activities[0].state)
    let guildChannels = newMember.guild.channels;

    var Cha = guildChannels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "general")

    if(newMember.activities[0].state === "hello") {
        Cha.send('hello !')
        .then(msg => {
            
            let GradeUser = bot.users.cache.find(user => user.id == newMember.userID);
            let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id == "742423876004216883");
            GradeUser.roles.add('742423876004216883')

        })
        .catch(console.error)
    }

});
```

And here's the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\Dev\Effectivement Bot\index.js:320:29   
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I just want to solve the error with the role ( add the role )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a GuildMember object, not a user object.

*From discord.js guide*

> ## What is the difference between a User and a GuildMember?
>
> A lot of users get confused as to what the difference between Users and GuildMembers is. The simple answer is that a User represents a global Discord user and a GuildMember represents a Discord user on a specific server. That means only GuildMembers can have permissions, roles, and nicknames, for example, because all of these things are server-bound information that could be different on each server that user is in.

Replace `bot.users.cache.find()` with `msg.guild.members.cache.find()`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help